# Unable to import oenvino's opencv

Tags: opencv, openvino

I have followed openvino [installation guide](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_windows.html#set-the-environment-variables) for windows 10, but I'm still unable to import its cv2 module in spyder. please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate the initialization variable which is the setupvars each time you open a new terminal in order to be able to use OpenVINO and its dependencies.

You may try to use the Spyder's terminal to initiate it.

Navigate:cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021\bin\

Run: setupvars.bat

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by installing windows 10 SDK tool in Visual Studio 2019 and went back to rerun the [installation](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_windows.html) process.